# How to list tags from custom post type attachments?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags, advanced-taxonomy-queries

So I am trying to list out all the tags created for images uploaded within my custom post type only. I added in a snippet of code to my themes functions.php file to enable media categories and tags:

```
function wptp_add_tags_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

I am using the following code within my template file to generate a list of tags from my custom post type... but hopefully some fresh eyes can show me what I need to do to it to just show the tags I have generated on my images that are uploaded within this custom post type:

```
        <ul class="work_tags_nav">
            <li class="active"><a class="all">all.</a></li>
        <?php
            query_posts(array( 'post_type'=> 'work', 'taxonomy' => 'type', 'term' => 'case-study' ));
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $custom_post_tags = get_the_tags();
            if ( $custom_post_tags ) {
                foreach( $custom_post_tags as $tag ) {
                    $tags_arr[] = $tag -> name;
                }
            }
            endwhile; endif;
            if( $tags_arr ) {
                $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr );
             foreach( $uniq_tags_arr as $tag ) {
                 // LIST ALL THE TAGS FOR DESIRED POST TYPE
                 $sanitizeTag =  sanitize_title($tag);
                 $tag_link = get_terms('name', $tag, 'post_tag');
                 $tag_class = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '_', html_entity_decode($tag)); // This strips our sepcial characers and spaces, then replaces them with an underscore
                 //echo '<li><a class="'.$tag.'" href="'. get_tag_link($tag_link->term_id).'">' .$tag. '.</a></li>';
                 echo '<li><a class="'.$tag_class.'">' .$tag. '.</a></li>';
                 }
             }
         ?>
        </ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_the_tags() function in deed returns only terms of 'post_tag' taxonomy (tags). If you'd like to get terms of another taxonomies, you'd have to use get_the_terms function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

```
$custom_post_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type' ); //type is a name of custom taxonomy
```

or you can use wp_get_object_terms function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) where you can define more than one taxonomy

```
$custom_post_tags = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), array( 'type', 'post_tag', 'category' ) );
```

Hope I got your question corretly....

Comment: David, still not getting any results. Basically I am trying to pull an unordered list of all tags within my Media Library used when tagging images that are uploaded.

Comment: Than you need get_tems function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Comment: Thanks.. did the trick! `get_terms("post_tag", array('exclude' => '110, 120, 118, 115, 117, 119, 116, 132'));`